# Sizing of table view cell and table view header view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view which displays table view cells and a header view (search bar). I want the width of the table view cells to be **0.9 of the device screen size**, and the header view to have the same size. However, this is not possible because cells and the header view are all contained in a table view.

When I use layout anchor constraints everything gets resized (including the header view).

```
self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

// here's the 0.9 multiplier
self.tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
self.tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

How can I make sure that the table view header has the same width of the view controller, while keeping the table view width to be 0.9 of the main view?

Comment: I would try to create the header of constant width (the width of the ViewController) and then set the `clipsToBounds` property of your tableView to `false`. Not sure it will work, but worth a try.

Comment: Why not simply make your table the width of the screen... make your header view the full width... and then make your cells 0.9 of the width?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks. The problem is that I don't know how to make my cells 0.9 of the width. I haven't found any way or method to do it.

Comment: How are you designing your cells? You can use constraints inside cells just as easily as using them for the table...

Comment: Thanks. I have subclassed a table view cell and use this custom class in the `cellForItem` method. Should I add constraints in that method?

Comment: Are you doing this all from code, not using Storyboard / Interface Builder to design the cell?

Comment: Yes, everything is done programmatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139987/discussion-between-donmag-and-cesare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom cell "starts with" a ContentView, which uses uses the table view's insets to set its width...

So, if you have a bunch of elements / objects that you are adding to the content view...

Your best bet is to probably first add a standard `UIView` as a "container view"... (just my naming of it)...

Then, set the constraints on that "containing view" to be 0.9 of the width of the contentView...

All of the elements you add to that "containing view" will be constrained *relative to it* and thus will all stay inside the 0.9-width overall...

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to try to adjust the constraints of a `TableViewCell` or its `contentView`.  However, you can just set both those views to have a background color of `.clear` and then add subviews to the `contentView` with the constraints you want.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    let smallerView = UIView()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame)
        smallerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(smallerView)
        smallerView.widthAnchor.contraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
        smallerView.heightAnchor.contraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Should I add the table view cell to the `smallerView`?

Comment: You need to make a custom tableviewcell and add smallerViews to each of the cells.  See my update